# PHP mssql error

Tags: php

I get the following error from php when using the mssql module.

```
PHP Warning:  mssql_query(): message: Incorrect syntax near 'i'. (severity 15) in /var/www/html/inc/get_port.php on line 19
PHP Warning:  mssql_query(): General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 15) in /var/www/html/inc/get_port.php on line 19
PHP Warning:  mssql_query(): Query failed in /var/www/html/inc/get_port.php on line 19
```

The line in question is this:

```
$query = "SELECT i.NodeID as \"NodeID\" i.InterfaceName as \"Int Name\", i.Caption, i.InterfaceAlias as InterfaceAlias, i.IfName, nd.IP_Address as \"IP Address\", nd.Caption as \"Node Name\", nd.Location, nd.machinetype From [Interfaces] as \"i\", [NodesData] as \"nd\" where i.NodeID = nd.NodeID and (nd.MachineType LIKE \"CISCO CATALYST%\" OR nd.MACHINETYPE LIKE \"PROCURVE%\") and (nd.Location LIKE \"F208%\"  and i.InterfaceAlias = \"E26\") ";
```

Any hints where it does not like my labels?  this command when ran originally as this works fine on the mssql server

```
SELECT    i.NodeID as "NodeID", i.InterfaceName as "Int Name", i.Caption, i.InterfaceAlias as InterfaceAlias, i.IfName, nd.IP_Address as "IP Address", nd.Caption as "Node Name", nd.Location, nd.machinetype From [Interfaces] as i, [NodesData] as nd where i.NodeID = nd.NodeID and (nd.MachineType LIKE 'CISCO CATALYST%' OR nd.MACHINETYPE LIKE 'PROCURVE%') and (nd.Location LIKE 'F208%'  and i.InterfaceAlias = 'E26' )
```

Comment: you have a comma missing after the \"NodeID\"

Comment: Try to use `'` instead of `\"`, it will make your life easier

Comment: _"This command when ran originally as this works fine on the mssql server"_ Now print out `$query` and compare the two with your eyes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query you are executing directly on MSSQL server has comma next to second `i` while query executed in PHP doesn't.

```
$query = "SELECT i.NodeID as \"NodeID\" <- there should be a comma here
```